# Visual Studio 2019 - No data sources to show for the selected project

Tags: visual-studio, clr

I am relatively new to Visual Studio and apologies if I word things incorrectly, but I am currently going through [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a5f59f/how-to-create-log-in-form-in-visual-studio-and-connection-wi/) for a login system that I can connect to my SQL Server database. I could work up to step 8 where you need to connect the SQL Server using Data Binding, but the menu gives me no option to add a new data source:
[(Image showing no options when I select data binding in Properties)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OoQX.png).
The data source box also gives me no option to add a new data source. Instead, when I right click it says that no commands are available: [(Data source box)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1sbc.png).
I am currently using the CLR .NET Framework (4.8). I have tried to look for solutions to this, but I cannot find anything that applied to me. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to [ask]. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.